# Android linear acceleration sensor redundancy?

Tags: android, android-sensors

Accoprding to this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html

In modern Android devices you can measure 1) acceleration (including gravity), 2) linear acceleration (excluding gravity), 3) gravitational acceleration, all along the X,Y,Z axes.

Is the linear acceleration reading simply the accelerometer reading - gravity reading? Or differently put, is the accelerometer equal to the linear acceleration + gravitational acceleration? I.e., there are 9 different data points being sensed, and I'm trying to figure out whether three are redundant.

Comment: I haven't performed the math on the raw sensor values; but my perception when working with the Android accelerometer was that the linear acceleration *sensor* removed the gravitational force from each axis in hardware or low-level code as this would be much more efficient than performing the calculations in Java.  It is safe to assume that your device has a single (hardware) accelerometer, and you could verify this with research about your device.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, there is a single hardware sensor for acceleration (apart from gyroscope, which measures angular acceleration).

Gravity is a "fake" sensor, which value is extracted from the raw acceleration by a low-pass filter.

Linear acceleration is, indeed, just the difference.

As @mstrthealias pointed out, even if this is redundant, it might be more efficient to directly get the linear acceleration rather than compute the difference in Java, but I'm just speculating here.